# Why are many sessions faster in MongoDB than one?

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance, mongodb-.net-driver

To use transactions in MongoDB you have to start a session first. When you have many transactions, you can either reuse an existing session or create a new one for every transaction.

I benchmarked (code below) both options and the result is puzzling me. Using a fresh session for each transaction seems to be significantly faster (~2 to 3 times faster) than using a single session for all transactions.

Can anybody explain why this is so? How do sessions work under the hood? What are their implications? What costs do the imply (and when and why)? I really want to understand and I am grateful for any pointers.

```cs
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

coll1.InsertOne(new BsonDocument { { "Seq", 0 } });
sw.Start();
for (int i = 1; i <= reps; i++) {
    using (var session = client.StartSession()) {
        session.StartTransaction();
        coll1.InsertOne(session: session, document: new BsonDocument { { "Seq", i } });
        session.CommitTransaction();
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"{reps / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} OP/s with fresh sessions.");

coll2.InsertOne(new BsonDocument { { "Seq", 0 } });
sw.Restart();
using (var session = client.StartSession()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= reps; i++) {
        session.StartTransaction();
        coll2.InsertOne(session: session, document: new BsonDocument { { "Seq", i } });
        session.CommitTransaction();
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"{reps / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} OP/s with common session.");
```

I also tried running the single session code first giving me the same result.

Comment: So there's a rather significant error in your code. [`InsertOne()`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollectionBase_1_InsertOne.htm) actually has `InsertOneOptions` which is where you include the `session` as the **second** argument. The **first argument** is the document content to be inserted. So your code is attempting to insert the "session object" into the database on each iteration. Also the test is really synthetic considering nobody would realistically use `InsertOne()` in a loop like this and `InsertMany()` exists for that exact purpose.

Comment: Please see the current documentation of [InsertOne()](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_InsertOne.htm). The **first argument** is an `IClientSessionHandle`.

Comment: The test is intentionally synthetic. I used a single `InsertOne()` to keep the cost of the actual work as low as possible and primarily measure the cost of session creation/reuse.

Comment: No it's not the first argument. Look at my link which says "current" and therefore is the same as the 2.7.2 revision. It is in the .NET API ( and every other language API ) the **second** option. Not seeing this reproduce in a couple of quick tests for nodejs or python either.

Comment: The link to the version you posted above did not have session support at all (if you look the the assembly tag in your link it says version 2.2.0). But I changed my code to use named parameters just to be sure and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: Ummm "current" means "current"! Cannot reproduce. Show some metrics, general hardware specs and MongoDB version in use

Comment: The URL of the documentation for the C# driver seems to have changed from [api.mongodb.com](https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/) to [mongodb.github.io](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/) as https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/ shows only versions up to 2.2.0.

Comment: MongoDB is 4.0.9 running within an VMware Workstation on a Core i5 vPro Windows 10 notebook.

Comment: There's no point in arguing semantics over where the current documentation is. The basic point is that the test is flawed. The real problem is in the repeated calls to `startTransaction()` on the same session instance. It's just not realistic. Whilst I can "somewhat" reproduce your claims, what I really see is simply moving the `start` and `commit` **outside** of the loop reduces the time of either of your tests by **half**, and **doing it properly** ( with `InsertMany()` ) takes little over a second for 10,000 documents as opposed to much longer in the contrived loops.

Comment: I totally agree with you. My core question was, nevertheless, why reusing an existing session is slower than creating a new one, which seems counter intuitive to me. I really want to understand, what's going on under hood with sessions.

Comment: Trying to convey to you that your "test" is neither **real world** or intended usage. In real world usage you would have a block of code which returned a reference to a session **once**, then you would start a transaction and **at most** you would have many operations which used that current reference in the current transaction scope. When done you would "commit", and finally leave the block where the session handle goes out of scope. There is no real world case where you would start 100's or 1000's of transactions on the same session handle in scope.

Comment: So Yes, basically there's a memory leak here that slows things down. But you just don't ever use it that way.

Comment: My use case is that I have a few hundred data processing objects that are waiting for events to process which run on a thread pool. Upon receiving an event a processing object executes usually just a few operations within a transaction and then commits. The question to me was, whether it is smart to reuse a pool of sessions for many such transactions.

Comment: So now you know it is not smart. Don't keep a pool and just ask for a session handle in the scope where you actually need it. If you were intended to use a "pool", then it would have been added as a "driver feature" just like connection pooling is. All the ( official ) code examples tell you to grab an instance at the time of usage.

Comment: Ah, this is so typical SO when someone who has **no clue** about the answer keeps on wasting everyone's time with their pointless comments about how contrived and unrealistic the example is and otherwise attempt to discredit the question, simply because they're irritated by the inability to provide an answer. As to the question: use your favorite C# profiler and compare. Most probably the driver does something differently in the two cases. You can build one from source which should help with profiling.

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#sessions).

> Isolation
>
> Operations within a causally consistent session are not isolated from
>   operations outside the session. If a concurrent write operation
>   interleaves between the session’s write and read operations, the
>   session’s read operation may return results that reflect a write
>   operation that occurred after the session’s write operation.

It means that operations of different sessions could go in parallel without frequent blocking.